# Python:[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)

Tags: python, ssl

I am getting `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)` for  python request.get and request.post calls.
Previously the above calls were working fine,now we introduced HTTPS redirection in IIS,and we are gettng this error.
So I changed the calls from
`requests.get(url)` to `requests.get(url, verify=False)` and 
`requests.post(url, data=data)` to `requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False)`. Then the POST Web APIS are not reachable.
Then I tried changing the URL from Http to Https and made verify=false ,in this case the request calls are working fine but am getting warnings like "its better to add certificate verification".
I also tried to create an X.509 (.CER) certificate file from Server side certificate option and gave the .cer file path for verify(verify='path\to\cer file),still am geetting "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]".
Is there anything wrong in this approach.
Anyone face this issue earlier?
Please share if you have any insights about this issue.

Thanks in advance
Susmitha

Answer (score 1):

This issue not from your code, but from API server's.
`SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` is raised when server's SSL certificate is not verified by CA, as you know, you should add server-side-ssl to your local `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`.

This [link: ssl-cert-verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) would be helpful.

Remember you should use `.post(verify='/path')` to `CA_BUNDLE file`.

If you are using certificate file like CER file, you can consider doing like this:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.cert = '/path/client.cert'
```

Comment: Hi Beomi,   Thanks for your reply.What is CA_BUNDLE.Where it will be pointing? If am using cert file then while generating that file i used X.509 (.CER) certificate file from Server side certificate is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of openssl which provided by your system, use this cmd:

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

I fixed this issue just now after I updated the openssl from 2014 version to 2016 version.